# Blender won't open on macOS Mojave

Tags: startup-file

I've been using blender for a couple weeks on macOS High Sierra and yesterday I downloaded something from blender cloud and blender wouldn't open after that.  The icon bounces for a minute as if its opening then freezes and says application not responding before anything even comes up. I tried deleting the add on & deleting blender and re downloading blender and then called Mac and they had me update my software to macOS Mojave 10.14.6.  None of that worked..
I tried going into security and privacy and there is no "open anyway" option.
Can anyone help me? I don't know what I did but I am already addicted to blender and need to get it working :) Thank you soooo much in advance

Comment: Welcome, polaphoenix. Did you try to use the zip version?

Comment: thank you! hmm, I don't see a zip version for Mac?

Comment: You're right. There's no zip version for mac. You can try another build at https://download.blender.org/release/

Comment: Ok so I tried all 4 Mac versions under 2.8 and had the same problem, then was able to download the 2.79 version and open it... not sure what to do now, if I should invest in learning this older version or still try and get the 2.8 up and running.. Thank  you so much for the link and suggestions

Comment: Ended up having to delete the startup file, then re downloaded 2.8 and its working great now  